# php multiple reffering domains not working

Tags: php

with single domain as reffering domain code works fine

`<?php  $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; if (preg_match('~site1\\.com$~', parse_url($referrer, PHP_URL_HOST)))`

but when i add more sites as reffered domain nothing happens only blank page

`<?php  $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; if (preg_match('~site1\\.com$~'| '~site2\\.com$~' | '~site3\\.com$~', parse_url($referrer, PHP_URL_HOST)))`

how can i add more sites as reffering domains

Answer (score 1):

I would use the | operator inside one and only one regex (I am not sure multiple regex using pipe are allowed in php) :

```
<?php  $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; if (preg_match('~(site1\.com|site2\.com|site3\.com)$~', parse_url($referrer, PHP_URL_HOST)))
```

additionally, I don't understand why you escape twice the dot character.

Comment: it worked with your suggestion but when if reffering domain use www in the link, it'll not work

Comment: it worked with your suggestion but when reffering domain contains www it not works but gives 404 error

Comment: it's generally a bad idea (especially for search engines) to let domain be accessible with AND without www
You should redirect between one to the other and adapt your code regarding what you choose.

Comment: You can redirect from server side or dns, or if you can't either the first or second way there is php's function header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently", false, 301); and header('Location: YourDestinationLocation'); that can be used.

Comment: you are right to move www to non www through 301, but still i am confiused is there a way to add multiple domains into this <?php  $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; if (preg_match('~site1\\.com$~', parse_url($referrer, PHP_URL_HOST))) because with single domain with or without www works fine only wana add more domains

Comment: there is also another alternative solution <?php if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'example.com')) {
  echo '<div id="main">Title</div>';
} ?>
this also works fine but can you add more domains to this code? <?php if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'example.com'| 'example2.com')) {
  echo '<div id="main">Title</div>';
} ?>

Comment: I don't think either strstr or preg_match were made to accept pipes and several strings in php.
The solution I showed you with | inside one and only one regex should be satisfying for every list of domains, including www or not.